# Resolving detached DOM element in Cypress without cy.wait()

Tags: cypress

I get an error with the following code

```
describe('b-type test STEP 1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/contact/b-type')
  })
  it('Error message pop outs when clicking on the next button after not selecting a category', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=next]').click()
    cy.get('.bp3-toast-message').contains('Please select a category.').should('exist')
  })
})
```

[image]

I believe this happens because my DOM elements are detached immediately after I run

```
cy.visit('/contact/b-type')
```

before each test, and Cypress needs some time before the DOM gets attached.

If I add a `cy.wait(1000)` before each `click()` event, the error is resolved.

```
describe('b-type test STEP 1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/contact/b-type')
  })
  it('Error message pop outs when clicking on the next button after not selecting a category', () => {
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('[data-cy=next]').click()
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('.bp3-toast-message').contains('Please select a category.').should('exist')
  })
})
```

However, I understand that using `cy.wait()` in this way is not part of the best practices. Is there a better way of resolving the detached DOM error after a page visit without using `cy.wait()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are immediately invoke action on an element after the `cy.visit()`, it would be best to append a `.should()` before invoking any actionably commands. So all you'll have to do is this:

```
describe('b-type test STEP 1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/contact/b-type')
  })
  it('Error message pop outs when clicking on the next button after not selecting a category', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=next]')
      .should('be.visible') // assert element is visible or retry previous command
      .click()
    cy.get('.bp3-toast-message')
      .contains('Please select a category.')
      .should('exist')
  })
})
```